# Tango / Unity: is TangoApplication.m_enableDepth immutable at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am messing with ways to turn TangoPointCloud on and off at runtime, and I suppose that I can turn the whole script off, but I was hoping that I could set:

```
SetDepthCameraRate(TangoEnums.TangoDepthCameraRate.DISABLED);
```

or:

```
m_enableDepth = false;
```

But neither of these methods seems to work at runtime, is this a similar issue to the fact that:

```
tangoApplication.m_3drResolutionMeters
```

cannot be changed at runtime currently?

Comment: tiny update: disabling the entire TangoPointCloud.cs has no effect at runtime, seeming to indicate that the state of this script is immutable.

Comment: you should be able to turn off the whole script and it will stop the point cloud and meshing. what if you disable the whole game object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I revisited this issue today and the compiled .apk that was not working is now working correctly. The only thing that has changed is a few reboots, so there must be an issue that causes the Tango SDK to misbehave in between app launches that a reboot can solve. Frustrating, but it appears that both of these methods work correctly to stop the point cloud generation:

```
SetDepthCameraRate(TangoEnums.TangoDepthCameraRate.DISABLED);
m_enableDepth = false;
```